# ERRNO: 8192 when trying to send mail

Tags: php, email, pear

I have the following code which works when i put it in any blank php page,but when i try to put the code in another php page where i already have some codes in it, i get the error:

> ```
> ERRNO: 8192
> TEXT: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated
> LOCATION: C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Mail.php, line 154,
> ```

```
 include('Mail.php');
        $mail = Mail::factory("mail");

        $headers = array("From"=>"xyz@gmail.com", "Subject"=>"Your order has been placed   ");
        $body = "lol";
        $mail->send("abc@live.com", $headers, $body);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have an old version of PEAR::Mail. Could be version 1.1.14, the last stable version before the current stable version 1.2.0.

Try

```
pear channel-update pear.php.net
pear upgrade Mail
```

to get the latest version.

---

edit: This is not actually part of the answer but doesn't fit in a comment either:

For debugging purposes replace the factory function in pear/Mail.php by

```
function &factory($driver, $params = array())
{
  $driver = strtolower($driver);
  echo '<pre>Debug: driver=', $driver, "</pre>\n";
  echo '<pre>Debug: include_path=', get_include_path(), "</pre>\n";
  echo '<pre>Debug: cwd=', getcwd(), "</pre>\n";
  echo '<pre>Debug: __FILE__=', __FILE__, "</pre>\n";

  require_once 'Mail/' . $driver . '.php';
  $class = 'Mail_' . $driver;
  if (class_exists($class)) {
    $mailer = new $class($params);
    return $mailer;
  }
  else {
    throw new Exception('Unable to find class for driver ' . $driver);
  }
}
```

Comment: In a command shell. How did you get the version of PEAR::Mail that you already have? Didn't you use `pear install Mail`?

Comment: i get no valid packages found

Comment: Sounds like the Mail package hasn't been installed properly. Try `pear install -a Mail`. Or use http://swiftmailer.org instead of PEAR:Mail

Comment: it has installed Mail 1.2.0
Is it ok?

Comment: Call to undefined method PEAR_Error::send() in C:\xampp\htdocs\final\testmail.php on line 30
Now i get this

Comment: Something went wrong with `$mail = Mail::factory("mail");`. It probably didn't find pear/mail/Mail.php. I'd throw away that "installation" of pear and start anew from http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.php

Comment: When i test the code by running:http://localhost/final/testmail.php in the browser, it works, BUt in the actual page where i need this code it does not work. Even if i out the code in a function and i try to does call that function, it does not work. It works only if i put the url directly into the browser :( I dnt know what to try anymore

Comment: Maybe the pear directory isn't in the include\_path. `echo 'path:', get_include_path();` can tell.

Comment: No the pear directory is in the include path

Comment: Debug: driver=mail 
Debug: include_path=.;\xampp\php\PEAR
Debug: cwd=C:\xampp\htdocs\final
Debug: __FILE__=C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Mail.php

Comment: ...and then an exception message or what happens?

Comment: Nothing happens. The above is displayed and no email is sent

Comment: Sorry, no idea then. $mail was an instance of PEAR_Error and not a mailer class according to `Call to undefined method PEAR_Error::send()`. That's why I expected the "new" code to throw the exception instead. Now that it doesn't... I'm clueless. Going to delete the answer soon as this is getting nowhere.

Comment: Thanks for your help though! Could you suggest me another way to send mail using php? Some links would be great!