# Execute codes in a different page but remain on the same actual php page

Tags: php, email, pear

I have a complicated problem here..I have codes to send mail using PEAR which i have tested in a php page called testmail.php.
Now i have my actual application an a page called Cart.php where i have a button called Place Order. When i click on this button, it actually redirects to a url called :
http://localhost/final/index.php?OrderSuccessful which actually displays a message on the page and sends an email. The problem is that when i put the code for email in Cart.php, i get errors. But when i put the url http://localhost/final/testmail.php it actually works. 
So i was thinking, is there a way to execute the codes from that testmail.php by remaining on the page Cart.php?

```
include('Mail.php');
$mail = Mail::factory("mail");

$headers = array("From"=>"xyz@gmail.com", "Subject"=>"Your order has been placed   ");
$body = "lol";
$mail->send("abc@live.com", $headers, $body);
```

I get the error

> Assigning the return value of new by
>   reference is deprecated

Comment: ERRNO: 8192 
TEXT: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated 
LOCATION: C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Mail.php, line 154,

Comment: Deprecated shouldn't normally be an error.  Perhaps you can change your error_reporting settings and then you can ignore it - http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have old code. Follow the tips here:

[ERRNO: 8192 when trying to send mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612684/errno-8192-when-trying-to-send-mail)